# Value from next row - DAX

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, rank

I'm trying to create following calculated column in Power BI data model:

[image]

Logic:
Sort dataset based on ID & Start Date and show value from column Status from next row.

(1 ID can have one or more SubIDs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for a calculated column:

```
Expected Result = 
VAR _start_date = [Start Date]
VAR _id = [ID]
VAR _t = FILTER(TableName, [ID] = _id && [Start Date] > _start_date)
VAR _next_date = MINX(_t, [Start Date])
RETURN MINX(FILTER(_t, [Start Date] = _next_date), [Status])
```

[image]